# PHP Page: Dropdown always selects the first value

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have multiple dropdown lists on my PHP page and all are created like this:

```
<?php
//Select values from MySQL Database
$query = "SELECT name FROM Player";
$result = mysql_query($query);

//Show DropDownList
echo '<select name="players" onclick="sortlist(this)">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ))
{ 
        echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';   
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Now in case you haven't noticed I call a javascript function "sortlist(this)" on every dropdownlist i have. This function just order values alphabetically. You can check the script:

```
<script>

function sortlist(selElem) {
        var tmpAry = new Array();
        for (var i=0;i<selElem.options.length;i++) {
            tmpAry[i] = new Array();
            tmpAry[i][0] = selElem.options[i].text;
            tmpAry[i][1] = selElem.options[i].value;
        }
        tmpAry.sort();
        while (selElem.options.length > 0) {
            selElem.options[0] = null;
        }
        for (var i=0;i<tmpAry.length;i++) {
            var op = new Option(tmpAry[i][0], tmpAry[i][1]);
            selElem.options[i] = op;
        }
        return;
    }
</script>
```

All my dropdownlists are inside a form tag like this:

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" action="" method="post">
```

The script is running ok, i have the dropdownlist ordered alphabetically, but whenever i select one value, it always shows the first one.

Comment: Always use onchange() function with select.

Comment: @Rohit He wants it sorted when the user clicks on it, before the menu opens up, not after they select something.

Comment: @Rohit thank you, i read about it, but one way or another it works. My problem is with the selected value, is always the first one (even if I use onchange() still doesnt work)

Comment: @Barmar I know that but I want to correct him with function use also.

Comment: @Coutinho - you are sort list using javascript but not replace existing dropdown with newly sorted dropdown.

Comment: What do I need to update? My JS is wrong?

Comment: There are two options:
1. You can fetch sorted record in query (in this case you don't need to call JS function & sort)
2. You can use ajax. (After call sort function make an ajax call which will replace old dropdown with new one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this

```
<body>
    <select id="select_id" >
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="Z">Z</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="E">E</option>
        <option value="A">A</option>
    </select>
</body> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sortlist(selElem) {
        var tmpAry = new Array();
        for (var i=0;i<selElem.options.length;i++) {
            tmpAry[i] = new Array();
            tmpAry[i][0] = selElem.options[i].text;
            tmpAry[i][1] = selElem.options[i].value;
        }
        tmpAry.sort();
        while (selElem.options.length > 0) {
            selElem.options[0] = null;
        }
        for (var i=0;i<tmpAry.length;i++) {
            var op = new Option(tmpAry[i][0], tmpAry[i][1]);
            selElem.options[i] = op;
        }
    return;
    }
    sortlist(document.getElementById('select_id'));
</script>
```

REASON: your script always sorting your select on onclick no matter whether you are selecting value it is sorting and reseting your selected value.

so call your script only once for sorting after you have render your select element

Comment: I lost connection with my server, give me some time to get it back so i can test if it works.

Comment: Oh nice it works! :D Thank you!  So i needed this on my code: sortlist(document.getElementById('select_id')); So simple, shame on me!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM Player ORDER BY name ASC";
```

How about this

```
function sortlist(elem) {
  arrTexts = new Array();
  for(i=0; i<elem.length; i++)  {
    arrTexts[i] = elem.options[i].text;
  }

  arrTexts.sort();

  for(i=0; i<elem.length; i++)  {
    elem.options[i].text = arrTexts[i];
    elem.options[i].value = arrTexts[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Im learning javascript :) But thank you for your comment. That still doesn't solve this problem!

Comment: Its not at all a MySQL query related issue, there might be issue in js!

Comment: Imagine a dropdownlist with values = {A, B, C, D, E, F}
If i choose F or other, it shows A.

Comment: @Chandresh i removed the JS, and used Joni Salmi sugestion and still doesn't work.

Comment: OK nvm, with this solution it works! But i really want with JS :( Can you guys help me out?